# combining two batch file into one

Tags: video, batch, matroska

I'm using two commands on for removing subtitles audio etc. and the other one is to merge subtitle with  mkv file in the same folder.

This for removing the subtitle or audio:

```
FOR /F "delims=*" %%A IN ('dir /b *.MKV') DO "C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" -o "fixed_%%A" -s !1,2 --compression -1:none "%%A"
```

and this one for merging mkv with srt file:

```
 for %%A IN (*.mkv) do (
"C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" -o "remux-%%~nxA" "%%~A" --forced-track "0:yes" --default-track "0:yes" --track-name "0:Arabic" --language "0:ara" "%%~nA.srt"
 )
```

Now, each one it's taking considerable amount of time, I was trying to combine them but it didn't work can you please help with that.

Comment: You have two *different* `for` statements - are the two commands intended to be working on exactly the the same set of files?

Comment: Yes exactly. I need these two commands to be working on the same set of files. means that I want to run one batch file to remove subtitles or audio embedded with mkv and after that merge the srt files Present in the folder with mkv after it removes the embedded subtitles and audio.

Answer (score 1):

## 1. Combine loops

Step one is to combine the two for-loops into one

```
for %%A IN (*.mkv) do (

   "C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" ^
         -o "fixed_%%A" ^
         -s !1,2 ^
         --compression -1:none ^
         "%%A"

   "C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" ^
         -o "remux-%%~nxA" ^
         "%%~A" ^
         --forced-track "0:yes" ^
         --default-track "0:yes" ^
         --track-name "0:Arabic" ^
         --language "0:ara" ^
         "%%~nA.srt"

)
```

I have used the caret character (^) to allow a command to continue onto several lines. This makes it easier to read and edit.

To make things easier later, lets excpand the short form of option names (like `-s`) to their full-name (like `--subtitle-tracks`) as this makes it easier to follow what is going on.

```
for %%A IN (*.mkv) do (

   "C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" ^
         --output "fixed_%%A" ^
         --subtitle-tracks !1,2 ^
         --compression -1:none ^
         "%%A"

   "C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" ^
         --output "remux-%%~nxA" ^
         "%%~A" ^
         --forced-track "0:yes" ^
         --default-track "0:yes" ^
         --track-name "0:Arabic" ^
         --language "0:ara" ^
         "%%~nA.srt"

)
```

By itself, combining two loops into one wont speed things up significantly  but it is a necessary first step. Try it out on a small set of files (copy three to a "test" directory and run the batch file there) Make sure it works before continuing.

## 2. Combine commands

The second step is to combine the two commands into one. This requires that you read and understand the [user-guide for the mkvmerge command](https://mkvtoolnix.download/doc/mkvmerge.html) - you can then know if the operations you want can be prformed in the same single command and what each of the items in the command does. Most likely the final command will combine most of the items from each command but not all of them

Notice that the order of items is important and that the general form of the command is

```
mkvmerge [global options] {-o out} [options1] {file1} [[options2] {file2}] [@options-file.json]
```

So you need to work out which of the options in your two commands are *global* options and put them all first.

We also need to understand what is meant by `%%~nxA`, `%%~A` and `%%~nA.srt`. See [What does %~d0 mean in a Windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/112135/477035)

Comment: why would you put two outputs if we're targeting the same files ? I didn't get that one more thing why are we calling the app two times on once is enough ?

Comment: @Mesh: You currently have two commands that run separately on each file and which produce the result you want (albeit slowly). You want to do two things (1. remove subtitles & audio, 2.merge subtitles). It is up to you to read the docs and come up with one mkvmerge command that does both. mkvmerge is not a standard part of Windows,  I'm not familiar with it, I dont do  video processing myself and have limited time to help others for free. I offer my answer as a form of teaching how to fish rather than offering you the caught fish.

Comment: I'm just asking to know is it stranded to have these command like this or not that's it.

Comment: @Mesh it isn't standard. I'm sure you can write one command that does both by studying the documents as I suggested. Try it and, if you have problems, post another question with details of your attempt